# reading inputstream of a socket

Tags: java, sockets, stream, readline

I have snippet

```
try {
    is = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(getSocket().getInputStream()));
}
catch(IOException e) {}
while(true) {println(is.readLine());}
```

Basically, I'm tring to println every single message that is sent to the input stream of the socket returned from getSocket().
My question is:

1. If there is no message sent to the socket, what value is returned
   from calling the readLine() method? Is it the null value or a null
   string (i.e. "") or is it something else?
2. When a message has been
   sent and has been printed out, what happened to the input stream of
   the socket then? Is it emptied out?
3. Do we need a way to check to
   only call the println() method only when the input stream HAS
   something to print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If nothing is sent through the stream - there is nothing to read yet. Your reader is just waiting.
2. It is emptied out only from the data you have received.
3. You should have the `while(true)` loop which is trying to read the line from the stream. You do not have to check anything.

If the socket is closed at the second side, reader is reading `null`. If the second side has exited without closing the socket, you get `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I would like to dig more in the 1st answer. What do you mean by waiting? If I have while(true) { println("debug"); println(is.readLine()); } then before the first message is sent to the stream, how many "debug"s are printeed out?

Comment: @TranTriet only one.

Comment: @TranTriet look how the server is written here: https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/ There is a loop which is listening to the client. After the client is connected, the program keeps waiting at `readLine()` method.

Comment: Thanks! Your answers tick all the boxes and them some!

Comment: (2) is. 'no', not 'yes'.

Comment: @EJP I see what you mean, it was misunderstanding. I have edited my answer, could you undo your down vote? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> If there is no message sent to the socket, what value is returned from calling the readLine() method? Is it the null value or a null string (i.e. "") or is it something else?

Neither. It blocks.

> When a message has been sent and has been printed out, what happened to the input stream of the socket then? Is it emptied out?

No. The data received has been removed from it. There may be further pending data waiting be read.

> Do we need a way to check to only call the println() method only when the input stream HAS something to print out?

No. It blocks until a line has been received, end of stream occurs, or an IOException is thrown.

Your read loop isn't correct. It doesn't detect end of stream. The usual way to write it is:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    // ...
```